# Highlighting duplicates in different color based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

Could you please suggest me how to highlight the duplicates in the same way, but based on the column Value.

eg:
Column A1 has the value "ID", B1 has "Name", C1 has "Title".

I wanna highlight the dups if column x1 is ID or Name alone. ("x" may be any column in the active worksheet).

I dont know how to proceed further since I'm a beginner to VBA

It's also fine if you append your code to the previous one.

I would be very thankful to you if you do this for me.

Comment: I cant see any code sample here, also do you mean that if e.g. b2 = mr pepe and x14 = mr pepe then x14 and b2 should be colored e.g. green ?

Comment: VBA or VBScript? They are not the same thing.

Comment: please show example (screenshot) what you have now and what you need

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding you want to highlight duplicates in your Worksheet,

try the following code, it will highlight as you add duplicate values to columns

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xlRng As Range
    Dim xlCel As Range
    Dim xlCol As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim XlStri As String

    '// Duplicates will be highlighted in red
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    For Each xlCol In Target.Columns
        Set xlRng = Range(Cells(1, xlCol.Column), Cells(Rows.Count, xlCol.Column).End(xlUp))
        Debug.Print xlRng.Address

        For Each xlCel In xlCol
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(xlRng, xlCel.Value) > 1 Then
                Set C = xlRng.Find(What:=xlCel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not C Is Nothing Then
                    XlStri = C.Address
                    Do
                        C.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                        Set C = xlRng.FindNext(C)
                    Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Address <> XlStri
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next xlCol

End Sub
```

To use the above code you need to put into the worksheet change event for the worksheet.

- Go to the worksheet you want to changes
- Go to the bottom, where the worksheet name appears (e.g. "Sheet1")
- Right click and select "View Code"

  Hope this helps